# Obj-C function declaration needs semi-colon?

Tags: objective-c, function

This is really simple but driving me nuts.

I am trying to implement a simple function in my Objective-C code. When I write this,

```
NSInteger Sort_Function(id id1, id id2, void *context) {

}
```

I get an error that a semi-colon was expected at the end of the declaration. However, I've seen this type of syntax in many, many examples. What could I possibly be doing wrong? If it matters, this is an iOS app and the function is nested in an if clause. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add some of the surrounding code. It's hard to tell what's going on here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function *definition* -- this snippet you posted -- is "nested in a `if` clause"? That's unfortunately illegal in C (and Obj-C by extension) -- all function declarations and definitions have to be at the top level of the file. Inside an `@implementation` section is also an option:

```
// Start of file

// Declaration or definition valid here
void my_func(void);    // Declaration
void my_other_func(void);
void my_third_func(void);

void my_func(void) {    // Definition
    return;
}

@implementation MyClass

// Definition also valid here
void my_other_func(void) {
    return;
}

- (void) myMethod {
    if( YES ){
        void my_third_func(void) {    // Invalid here
            return;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Is it possible you're confusing the function syntax with [block syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW3)?

```
// The caret indicates definition of a block, sort of an anonymous function
int (^myBlock)(int);
myBlock = ^int (int my_int) {
    return my_int;
};
```

Comment: This was indeed in the result of an if clause. Moving it to the implementation block seems to have solved the semi-colon issue. Thanks!